# Firebase database search returned no results

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to do a user lookup on my database that uses Firebase as a backend.I am trying to do a user search in my database that uses Firebase as backend. Through a searchview, I want to do the search to display the results in a recyclerview.
However when doing the search my code does not bring any results.

My code:

```
private fun configurarSearchView(view: View) {
        view.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                if (newText.isNotEmpty()) {
                    recyclerViewBeta.visibility = View.GONE
                    recyclerPesquisa.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    pesquisarUsuarios(newText.toUpperCase())
                    Log.i("PESQUISA", newText.toUpperCase())
                } else {
                    recyclerViewBeta.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    recyclerPesquisa.visibility = View.GONE
                }
                return true
            }
        })
    }

    private fun pesquisarUsuarios(texto: String) {
        Log.i("PESQUISA", "P: $texto")
        val query: Query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").orderByChild("nomePesquisa")
                .startAt(texto.toUpperCase()).endAt(texto.toUpperCase() + "\uf8ff")
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) { 
                    val usuario = ds.getValue(Usuario::class.java)!!
                    listaPesquisa.add(usuario)
                    Log.i("PESQUISA", "R: ${usuario.nomeExibicao}")
                }
                recyclerPesquisa.adapter?.let { it.notifyDataSetChanged() }
                val total: Int = listaPesquisa.size
                Log.i("PESQUISA", "total$total")
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
        })
```

Database:

```
"usuarios" : {
    "5P6DzPIEuiSKU5UYGo03AwSMTED3" : {
      "email" : "valter@teste.com",
      "id" : "5P6DzPIEuiSKU5UYGo03AwSMTED3",
      "nickExibicao" : "valter",
      "nomeExibicao" : "Valter dos Santos",
      "nomePesquisa" : "VALTER DOS SANTOS",
      "status" : "1577010585880",
    },
```

Why is data not being displayed? How to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You provide wrong child **users** to your database reference which should be **usuarios** according to your database structure. Try to use

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        .child("usuarios")
        .orderByChild("nomePesquisa")
        .startAt(texto.toUpperCase())
        .endAt(texto.toUpperCase() + "\uf8ff")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent();
```